# Como aplicar uma expressão matemática a todas as colunas de uma tabela no SAS?

Tags: normalização, sas

A expressão será aplicada a cada uma das 747 colunas de uma tabela/dataset.
Segue a expressão:
(variavel - media da variavel) / (valor maximo da variavel - valor minimo da variavel).

Será executada no SAS.

Answer (score 1):

O procedimento "proc standardize", chamado pelo comando `PROC STDIZE`, permite realizar diversas formas de padronização das variáveis numéricas de um dataset/tabela no SAS. Para a documentação completa do procedimento, [ver esse link](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/132/stdize.pdf).

Cada um dos métodos do PROC STDIZE atribui diferentes valores aos parâmetros `LOCAL` (local) e `SCALE` (escala). Esses parâmetros são então combinados com as variáveis originais conforme a função abaixo (ver páginas 5-6 da documentação):

```
resultado = soma + multiplicação x (original - local)/escala
```

Você pode verificar que nenhum dos métodos padrões do `PROC STDIZE` realiza automaticamente a transformação que você deseja. Então, a solução é combinar dois desses procedimentos, o `MEAN`: que salva a média das colunas como variável local; e o `RANGE`: que salva a amplitude das colunas como variável de escala (ver páginas 21 e 22 da documentação). Isso pode ser feito por meio do código:

```
* Salva as médias das variáveis numéricas;
proc stdize data=have method=mean out=out1 outstat=medias;
var _numeric_;
run;

* Salva a amplitude das variáveis numéricas;
proc stdize data=have method=range out=out1 outstat=amplitude;
var _numeric_;
run;

* Cria uma tabela com as médias como medida "local" e a amplitude como medidas de "escala";
data local_e_escala;
set medias (where=(_type_='LOCATION')) amplitude (where=(_type_='SCALE'));
run;

* Cria novo método de padronização utilizando a tabela criada como input; 
proc stdize data=have method=in(local_e_escala) out=want;
var _numeric_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá

No SAS existe uma library chamada SASHELP com views que podem ajudar em várias situações
Umas delas se chama VCOLUMN, onde contém o nome de todas as colunas de cada tabela.
Você pode filtrar essa view e selecionar as variáveis que quer utilizar e criar uma macro com loop para fazer os cálculos.